# Android Google Fit API: RecordingClient.subscribe failing with "com.google.android.gms.common.api.b: 8:"

Tags: android, google-fit

I have an application using Android Google Fit RecordingClient API to subscribe to fitness data.

On first installation, everything works fine.
However, if I subsequently manually revoke permissions to the app, then from the app request permissions again and subscribe again to fitness data, the last step (subscription) fails with `com.google.android.gms.common.api.b: 8:`.

Specifically, I'm doing this:

```
final RecordingClient recordingApi = Fitness.getRecordingClient(mContext, account);
recordingApi.subscribe(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
    e.printStackTrace();
});
```

`8` seems to mean INTERNAL_ERROR, as reported in [CommonStatusCodes](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes)

Being an opaque internal error, I'm hoping someone from the Google Fit team can take a look.

I'm using:

- play-services-auth:17.0.0
- play-services-fitness:18.0.0

Comment: Are you testing on Android 10? From API level 29, recording data of this type requires the ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION runtime permission.

Comment: I'm indeed using API level 29, and have acquired ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION permission, so this is not the cause of the issue.